# How to modify android source project(AOSP) and disable the private library check？

Tags: android, android-source

Since android 7.0, apps cannot visit private libraries with dlopen. My test program needs to use functions in library 'libart.so'. How to modify android source project(AOSP) and disable the private library check? I have AOSP Android 8.1.0 source code.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found the solution. Add the private libraries you want to access to file system/core/rootdir/etc/public.libraries.android.txt. Do not modify public.libraries.txt in out directory. Your system will not boot after modification.